# Selenium C# proxy

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, monodevelop

Здравствуйте! Как использовать прокси в Selenium?
Смотрел в интернете, вот что нашел:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile ();
Proxy proxy = new Proxy ();
proxy.HttpProxy = "localhost:8080";
profile.SetProxyPreferences (proxy);

IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver (profile);
```

Но у меня выходит такая ошибка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Селениум отвратно работает с прокси.

Потому я вижу лишь 2 выхода:

1. Использовать прокси для всего ПК
2. Использовать прокси вместе с PhantomJS драйвером/браузером. Там проблем в настройке прокси нет.